# Multithreading in flex web application

Tags: multithreading, actionscript-3, apache-flex

I am working on web application. In which i am stuck with some issue.

When i call some server function it will take time to get response. When response have high number of data. It will get data, process on that data and update GUI in background.

Upto that my application GUI freeze. I can not click on any part. I see some where that ActionScript support multithreading. I found some tutorial for that which is [here](http://www.bytearray.org/?p=4423). But, it is for desktop application only.

Is there any way i can handle this freezing of application/GUI in web application. It will decrease my application performance and looks very bad.

**Example:**

If i have list of data with checkbox and on checkbox click there is some process. Now, there is one button called "Select All". Now, if i click on "select all" then all check box selected and process on check selection is going and freeze the application upto process done.

like: I have following list

```
<s:List id="tempList" itemRenderer="CustomItemRenderer" 
                    dataProvider="{someList}" useVirtualLayout="false"/>
```

`ItemRenderer` have label and checkbox as following.

```
<s:CheckBox id="cCheckId" selected="{data.selected}" 
                change="onChangeHandler(event)" />
<s:Label id="lblTest"  />

protected function onChangeHandler(event:Event):void
{
    data.selected = !data.selected;
}
```

Now, on button Select all will select all check box.

```
<s:Button id="btnSelectAll" label="Select All" click="selectAllHandler(event)" />

protected function selectAllHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
  for(var i:int = 0;i<someList.length;i++)
  {
    someList[i].selected = true;
  }
}
```

Now, if `someList` have lots of data then it will freeze the screen.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Most likely you need asynchronous server calls and not multithreading. This search https://www.bing.com/search?q=actionscript+asynchronous may give you some starting points (or at least let you clarify if it what you need).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yes. Thank you. I have already used Asynchronous call. But application freeze for some seconds when there is some process is ongoing on high volume of data. like got high volume of data in response and make some process on it. I have edited my question.

Comment: I see. To my knowledge there were no multit-hreading  in ActionScript for web several years ago... Unless it changed you'd have to partition your data processing into smaller chunks and seriously consider how many items to show in lists/dropdowns at the same time.

Comment: `Worker` has been available since 11.4(?) for Air (Desktop) and Flash (Browser), Air Mobile Worker came later for Android and iOS. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Worker.html Now you can only update the UI from the main swf/thread and NOT a worker 'thread' (like most UI platforms), but you can background processing, asset loading, etc... Try http://jcward.com/github/JPEGEncoderTest_v0.2.1/JPEGEncoderTest.swf and https://github.com/jcward/AS3-Worker-Compat (there are a number of OSS wrappers for the `Worker` class to make it easy to work with..)

Comment: How many items do you have in your dataProvider and how many items do you display at once in the list? I'm pretty sure ActionScript can iterate trough at least 50.000 objects and set a property in each one in one go without problems. But if you are displaying all 50.000 items in the list and each itemrenderer will need to select its checkbox then you are in trouble :)

Comment: @Philarmon Yes i am displaying all the items in itemrenderer  and when select all then will check all the items. This is just a one thing. Same issue occurred at many place. Like there are grid having more than data and from outside i change any data like from popup and then i refresh datagrid with new changed data tehn it will freeze.

Comment: @Philarmon Yeah. I have more than 200 objects and make there proeprty selected  = true. And same issue happen when try to apply loop on one list having more than 250 records and make process to get particular records and make another two list and again apply some condition on that two list with condition then it will hang my screen for some amount of time

Comment: Do you do a lot of other calculations when you iterate trough your list? A general solution would be to display like 20-30 items in the list and let the user scroll for the rest. That way only 20-30 item renderers would be updated at a time and not all 250+

Comment: @Philarmon Yes i have. But my problem is that after doing all calculation one new list is generated which i need to display.

Answer (score 1):

The main idea behind the list and itemrenderers that you have a list (or datagrid) that displays like 30 items and then you can scroll to see the rest. Then you will only have 30 Itemrenderers that would be updated at once.

If you don't want to scroll you will need to distribute your item selection over several frames, something like that (untested, but you get the idea)

```
private static const ITEMS_AT_ONCE:int = 5000;
private var _currentIndex:int;

protected function selectAllHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    _currentIndex = 0;
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame); // this will call the onEnterFrame method on each frame rendered
}

private function onEnterFrame(e:Event):void
{
    // make sure we don't run out of bounds of the dataprovider's length
    var maxIndex:int = Math.min(_currentIndex + ITEMS_AT_ONCE, someList.length);

    // set selection for the current bunch
    for (var i:int = _currentIndex; i < maxIndex; i++)
    {
        someList[i].selected = true;
    }

    if (maxIndex == someList.length)
    {
        // We are done, remove enterframe listener
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);

        // I'm not sure but don't you need to refresh the dataprovider to reflect the changes in the ItemRenderers ?
        // (someList.dataProvider as ArrayCollection).refresh();
    }
    else
    {
        // update the _currentindex so we continue after this item on the next frame
        _currentIndex = maxIndex;
    }
```

Another possible solution - if you display all of them anyways - you might try to switch to a VGroup that will hold custom UIComponents (without MXML) for the items - this should speed up the rendering.

Comment: Whether the display components in the list are defined in MXML or not is irrelevant.  MXML is translated into Actionscript classes during compilation, so you generally don't get performance benefits from rewriting a component in pure AS.  Aside from that caveat, I think this answer is spot-on.

Comment: The point is that a VBox is more lightweight than a List and UIComponents WILL work faster than MXML components simply by avoiding tons of unneeded stuff like layout handling etc. MXML can get really slow in large applications, especially if you have a lot of containers

Comment: Again, MXML is irrelevant.  It's compiled to Actionscript.  The key point is that you *have lots of containers*.